# Ошибка при создании signed apk: please specify destination folder for the signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Всё прекрасно работало, пока студия не скачала себе обновления. Теперь выходит вот такая фигня:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что ему надо?

Comment: можно попробовать новый ключ создать

Comment: создал, не прокатило

Comment: До какой версии обновилось?

Comment: сегодня с утра обновлялось. Android Studio 3.3

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашел здесь [Cannot compile a signed APK in Android Studio 3.3][1]

1. Независимо от того, хотите ли вы APK или пакет, выберите Bundle
2. Даже если не требуется, установите флажок «Экспортировать зашифрованный ключ для регистрации опубликованных приложений».
3. Выберите любой файл
4. Нажмите Далее (это будет работать)
5. Дважды нажмите назад, выберите, если APK / Bundle, затем на следующей странице нет необходимости устанавливать флажок «Экспорт (…)», если не требуется.

   [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54196270/cannot-compile-a-signed-apk-in-android-studio-3-3